# Android Linux kernel information/inspection tool

Tags: android, linux, kernel

Is there a tool that can examine compiled kernels images for basic information about version/platform/device etc..

```
$<inspect-tool> zImage 
    Kernel version <X.XX.XX>, platform:<XXXX>, architecture<XXXX> etc..
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file` utility gives you some of that info:

```
# file /boot/gentoo-3.0.3 
/boot/gentoo-3.0.3: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 3.0.3-gentoo (root@mybox) #3 SMP Sat Aug 20 11:45:06 CEST 2011, RO-rootFS, root_dev 0x806, swap_dev 0x2, Normal VGA
```

Note that the arch is not correct (should be x86_64, but I guess the boot image for x86_64 is indeed a 32bit to start with).

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/anyway-to-extract-a-version-string-from-a-non-running-vmlinuz-506993/

but it is based on naive kernel image grepping, though it might solve your problem.

So in order to extract kernel version try something similar to:

```
grep -e "2\.[46]\.[0-9]*" ./vmlinuz
```

Note however, that it might be necessary to uncompress/decode the image first (I don't really know how android kernel image differ from regular Linux kernel).